# Outlook javamail error "A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected"

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

i try to open folder in my email but no luck.

this is the error:

```
Mar 06, 2019 1:24:14 PM Export run
SEVERE: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:960)
    at Export.getEmails(Export.java:115)
    at Export.run(Export.java:72)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:338)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.select(IMAPProtocol.java:656)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:926)
    ... 3 more
```

and this is what i am tried:

```
public void getEmails() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(DEBUG);

    store = null;
    store = session.getStore("imap");

    store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", this.userName, this.password);
    folder = store.getFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    int total_messages = folder.getMessageCount();
    if(total_messages > 0) {
        messages = folder.getMessages();
    }
}
```

the is the props:

```
props = new Properties();        
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");  
props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");    
props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", "imap-mail.outlook.com");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
```

the username and the password are ok.
I tried to change the password and I got another error with authenticated so the password and the username are correct.

i check the store.isConnected and I got true.
the problem in the line:

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

what can be the problem?

tnx a lot

Comment: That is very weird.  It looks like the server is unhappy for some reason.  You'll probably need to contact outlook.com support to find out what the error message means.

Comment: there is no explantion for this?

Comment: You tell me.  What did outlook.com support say when you contacted them?

Answer (score 0):

My Newly created mailbox took a long while to get all its configurations registered on O365 and for me at least it looked like timing issue, hope others find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error with imap and outlook.office365.com. I tried to set up the same account in Outlook to make sure it was working in general. Although I was able to add the account, when I actually tried to look at the inbox Outlook became unresponsive. So in my case, it was a problem with the account in general, not with how I was trying to connect.  I was able to successfully get to the inbox using pop3, it was only imap that gave me an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange and Office365 will accept IMAP connections and authenticate users on them even when the user doesn't have IMAP access permissions. It's only when the first IMAP command is issued after successfully authenticating that it fails with the error:

`User is authenticated but not connected`

To correct this, edit the user's permissions and ensure that IMAP is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. I had the same problem when moving from IMAP basic auth to to `XOAUTH2` (OAuth 2.0), since MS is [deactivating basic auth any minute now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online) (Oct 2022)

In my case the user was given IMAP permissions with Powershell:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "xxx@yyy.com" -User A92BE11B-ED50-4A1C-909F-52D12BE169E3 -AccessRights FullAccess
```

BUT the `xxx@yyy.com` was an alias for a real user `zzz@yyy.com` and I was trying to log in with `zzz@yyy.com`

Both of the following solutions worked:

1. Log in with the alias user `xxx@yyy.com` (same password as the real user)
2. Give the real user IMAP permissions:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "zzz@yyy.com" -User A92BE11B-ED50-4A1C-909F-52D12BE169E3 -AccessRights FullAccess
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In my case the user login name (email) was case sensitive. So User@domain.com is not user@domain.com and was getting this error instead of user not found error.